# Cannot import plottools to zoom in matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to zoom in on a part of a matplotlib graph, therefore I tried to import plottools (pip3 install plottools) and use it [in this way](https://pythonhosted.org/plottools/generated/plottools.zoom_axes.html). However I am unable to do so, getting the following error:

```
[myname@fedora P3]$ python mycode.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myname/mycode.py", line 3, in <module>
    import plottools as pt
  File "/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plottools/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    color = cs.Colorscheme(cs.default.colors,longnames=cs.default.longnames,cycle=cs.default.cycle)
AttributeError: module 'cs' has no attribute 'Colorscheme'
```

Here is my Python version:

```
[myname@fedora P3]$ python --version
Python 3.9.13
```

Comment: You can do this without plottools if that helps: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html

Comment: Note plottools was last updated 6 years ago - you may need to use a pretty old Matplotlib for it to work